# btn is click two times after async postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i am doing async postback using updatepanel. after async postback button is click two times.I dont know why I'm using jQuery to wire up some mouseover effects on elements that are inside an UpdatePanel. The events are bound in $(document).ready

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = body_load;
        function body_load()
        {
           BindEvents();
        }
        function BindEvents()
        {
            $(function ()


{$(".csstablelisttd").mousedown(function (e)
                {//mouse down code});
                    $("#contentPlaceHolderMain_btnFix").click(function (e)
                    {alert("Alert");//here alert is generate two times an then postback occurs
                       //btn click code
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelTableAppointment" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
     <table id="table" runat="server">
         //table data
        </table>

<script type="text/javascript">Sys.Application.add_init(body_load);
</script>
                    </ContentTemplate><Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFix" EventName="Click" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling `body_load` two times

here

```
 window.onload = body_load;
```

and here

```
Sys.Application.add_init(body_load);
```

which cause it to click two times

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching events twice: at loading of the page and after postback. You need to reset the handler, if you have to change the event handler

```
            function BindEvents()
            {
               $(function () {
                  $(".csstablelisttd").unbind('mousedown');
                  $("#contentPlaceHolderMain_btnFix").unbind('click');

                  $(".csstablelisttd").mousedown(function (e)
                      {//mouse down code});                                     
                  $("#contentPlaceHolderMain_btnFix").click(function (e)
                      {alert("Alert"); });
                }
            }
```

Comment: when i use unbind('click') mouse down code which is above btnclick event not working after asynpostback;